# Facebook auto renewal of long access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was wondering if anyone could clarify that all Facebook tokens are time bound and you can't actually have a token lasting more than 90 days without human interaction?

I have a simple page post facebook feed on a website, I now need to manually refresh the access token & update the request every 90 days? If I want this lovely facebook feed on a few of my client's websites I'm gonna have to make sure they don't go on holiday else their feed will go offline?

Comment: Why do you "need to manually refresh" the token? Automate it.

Comment: It requires authentication? Aren't you required to login to Facebook as a user? Unless you mean storing user facebook credentials on the server to automate that login process?

Comment: there is no way to "automate refreshing a token". that would be weird and would make the whole concept void. and no, storing credentials is not an option. extended page tokens are valid forever though.

Comment: also, "their feed will go offline" - hopefully you do not hardcode a token in clientside code? and hopefully you are caching the api results of getting the feed, instead of doing an api call for every user that hits the page? the feed can never go offline if you do it right, it may not be up to date if the token does not work anymore.

Comment: @luschn Is there any documentation on this? I can only find long-lived tokens for up to 90 days. I'm storing the token in a cms and using curl to grab the results

Comment: see answer. do not just store the token, also store the results, or you will hit api limits sooner or later - or the will be nothing to show if the api does not work for a  day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extended Page Tokens do not expire: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension

Make sure not to use any Token hardcoded in clientside code. Tokens always have to be kept secret. Also, cache API results on the server, so you do not have to hit the API for every user. Else, you may run into API limits.

You can also use webhooks to get realtime updates of your Page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/

**Edit: Extended Page Tokens do expire now, after 60 days.**

Comment: Thank you Luschn lots of knowledge, does Facebook have something similar to an event listener so you get real-time updates if you cache the posts? Instead of polling every X hours.

The token is stored serverside and only the output is visible to the client.

Comment: sure, i will add that to my answer. it is actually an even better idea ;)