# Refresh Facebook's long live access token when only pulling page feed

Tags: facebook, api

I'm trying to pull feeds from my FB page and display them on my website.

Facebook has a long live access token which expires within 60 days, so I need to find a way to automate a token refresh.

I've been doing research across StackOverflow but haven't found a successful solution to keeping my app working after the page access token expires.

Referencing this post: [Facebook auto renewal of long access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51085866/facebook-auto-renewal-of-long-access-token), the answer states "Extended Page Tokens do not expire", but this is not true since it does expire within 60 days.

To refresh the token, you need users to log in - but I don't have any user interaction. I just want to pull page feeds.

Is there a way for me to refresh the token without having to do it manually every 60 days?

Answer (score 0):

> Referencing this post: Facebook auto renewal of long access token, the answer states "Extended Page Tokens do not expire", but this is not true since it does expire within 60 days.

That is a relatively new restriction; they used to have no default expiry at all, but now they are limited to up to 60 days.

> Is there a way for me to refresh the token without having to do it manually every 60 days?

No, there is no way to do this without user interaction.

---

The whole point is that “long forgotten” apps people may have used at one point, won’t be able to use tokens acquired ages ago to continue requesting data “for all eternity”.

Comment: So there is no way to automate an access key refresh? Does this mean any app pulling Facebook feeds on their site will have it break every 60 days?

Comment: Only if they can’t be bothered to implement a mechanism to refresh it in time :-)

Comment: There is no way to “refresh” a user or page token without user interaction.

Comment: So how is a mechanism then put in place to refresh a token when just pulling feeds for users to view on a website?

Comment: Periodically check for long your token will still be valid, and then notify someone who can create a new one, when that value falls under a certain threshold ...

Comment: The check? No. Generating a new token? Yes.

Comment: What a headache! So we're going to have to set up automated email reminders then... but that's annoying! It's hard to imagine that everyone who simply wants to display feeds on their website will need to manually generate a new token every 2 months.